# How to simplify set expressions with union, intersection, and negation, in python

Tags: python, sympy, set-theory

Is there any in-built python library that can be used to generate simplified set expressions?

For examples, let's say, we have a set expression `(A∩B)U(A∩C)`. This can be simplified as `A∩(BUC)`.

Similarly `(A∩B)U(A∩!B)` can be simplified as `A`.

I am looking to implement this logic in python. I found that `sympy` can be used to simplify algebraic expressions like `x**2 + 2*x + 1` but I am not sure it handles set expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Set expressions are equivalent to boolean expressions, and `sympy` [can simplify those](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#simplification-and-equivalence-testing).

**Your examples:**

- `(A∩B)U(A∩C)` is equivalent to `(a & b) | (a & c)`,
- `(A∩B)U(A∩!B)` is equivalent to `(a & b) | (a & ~b)`,

```py
from sympy import *
a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c')

expr = (a & b) | (a & c)
simplify_logic(expr)  # produces: a∧(b∨c)

expr = (a & b) | (a & ~b)
simplify_logic(expr)  # produces: a
```

Some other examples [can be found here](https://ailtonbsj.github.io/simplifying-boolean-logic-expressions-with-sympy).

Comment: SymPy has a c++ code printer, so you can generate c++ equivalents of python expressions (see sympy/printing/cxx.py).